# Correlation matrix in pandas doesn't take some column into consideration

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I'm working on a classification problem using a dataset containing 39 attributes (38 independent features + the class attribute). When I try to calculate the correlation matrix the class attribute is not taken into consideration. To my knowledge, it should be included in the matrix as well.

```
len(heartdata.columns)
39
```

Since the number of columns in my dataframe is 39 then the correlation matrix should be of shape (39,39) but what I get is:

```
cor = heartdata.corr()
cor.shape
(38, 38)
```

Comment: Check for nulls in your data.

Comment: @AdityaK I already preprocessed the data and deleted all missing data

Comment: How many numeric columns do you have: `len(heartdata.select_dtypes("number").columns)`?

Comment: @MustafaAydın 38! I guess I know the cause of my problem now thanks! I should encode my class atrribute

Answer (score 2):

if your features are categorical, you should use `LabelEncoding`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

train = train_df   
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

for i in range(len(train.columns)):
    column = train_df.columns[i]
    train[column] = label_encoder.fit_transform(train_df[column])
    print(f"train {column} uniques: {len(train[column].unique())} ")

x = train
y = train_df['gender'].to_frame(name='gender')
```

Then you can get `Correlation Matrix`:

```
cor = x.corr()
print(cor)
```

and if you want use plot to show correlation between features, I suggest `heatmap` plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8),linewidth=10,edgecolor="#04253a" )
sns.heatmap(cor, annot=True, cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
plt.show()
```

**Output**:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My class attribute had a categorical type that's why corr() function didn't take it into consideration. A simple econding solved the problem.

```
le = LabelEncoder()
heartdata['class'] = le.fit_transform(heartdata['class'])
```